# Add Library JAR Files to EJB project

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven, m2eclipse

I have created Maven project project using m2eclipe plugin for Eclipse. I have choose ejb-javaee6 archetype and added few dependencies to pom.xml, Eclipse resolved this dependencies fine.

When I try to deploy this project on Glassfish server using WTP plugin, I can see that my dependencies did not copy to ear archive.

[There](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/verified/packaging.html) are few commons ways how to add library jar files to classpath of j2ee application. So I have to copy my dependencies in application server lib directory or copy it to top level of EAR file and provide manifest file of EJB module with classpath information.

What is the common way to achieve it ? I want eclipse/maven to automatically add jar files to classpath of EJB.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work properly you need to make sure to install m2eclipse-wtp integration plugin. It is not available as part of the default m2eclipse install. There may also be some flags you need to set in your pom.xml as the "jars that should be packaged with my app" is a subset of all jars on the application's classpath. Maven needs to know what to package, so that m2eclipse-wtp plugin can convey that information to Eclipse so that Eclipse functions like publish and export EAR work as expected.

Comment: As far as i remember this plugin name is m2extra and I already got it. The problem does not affect war files. Maven include dependencies jar under WEB-INF/lib for war file properly and package it to ear. The problem occurs only for ejb jar module

Comment: Is your pom.xml correct in showing this jar as visible to EJB. Can you build your EAR from command line using mvn and get the expected result?